There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) : io.swagger migration to org.openapitools
I am upgrading javax packages jakarta and need to migrate from io.swagger to org.openapitools
Below is the plugin which I am using currently.
Can someone please help with the detailed steps for migration.TIA.
        `<!--<plugin>
                

io.swagger
swagger-codegen-maven-plugin
2.2.2
                     <executions>
                         <execution>
                          <goals>
                           <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <output>${generated-sources-path}</output>
                        <inputSpec>src/main/sources/myService.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>jaxrs</language>
                        <templateDirectory>src/main/sources/mustache</templateDirectory>
                        <configOptions>
                            <title>my API</title>
                            <apiPackage>mypackagename</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>mymodel</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>myinvokerpkg</invokerPackage>
                            <sourceFolder>${generated-sources-java-path}</sourceFolder>
                            <serializableModel>false</serializableModel>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
                            <artifactVersion>1.0</artifactVersion>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>                   
            </executions>
        </plugin>**-->

I am quite new to this.Wanted to upgrade javax to jakarta and found that it requires swagger upgrade also. Found various documents online for spring but nothing related to jersy.
